# How to replace if a character is repeated more than a threshold value with a null or "" in vbs?

Tags: string, vbscript

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strSource = "C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"
Set File = fso.OpenTextFile(strSource, ForReading)
strText = File.ReadAll
File.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText,",","|")
Set File = fso.OpenTextFile(strSource, ForWriting, True)
File.WriteLine strNewText
File.Close
```

This is the code Im using and the result I get is: 
**xxxx|yyyy|zzzzz|||||||||||||||||||||**
The pipe character '|' must be replaced with 'null' or '' if its repeated more than five times and I have tried using trim, replace and mid functions but couldn't get the solution. Thanks

Comment: Just to understand your maybe underlying requirement: do you expect a fixed number of pipes in all lines? Or will the replacement you are looking for potentially yield lines with more and with less pipes?

Comment: every line will have pipes after each string but it shouldnt extend for more than five times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to limit the "|" to 5 consecutive entries?
There may be a prettier way, but this would work

```
Do While InStr(1, strNewText, "||||||") > 0
    strNewText = Replace(strNewText, "||||||", "|||||")
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but im trying to remove the pipes and replace with null if it exceeds five times

Comment: Do While InStr(1, strNewText, "|||||") > 0
    strNewText = Replace(strNewText, "|||||","")
Loop

Comment: This will replace 6 pipes by 5 even when they occur in the middle of a line, not at the end.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops):

```
\|{5,}
```

as follows:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = "C:\Users\Desktop\test.csv"
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path, ForReading)
strText = file.ReadAll
file.Close

Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Global = True
re.Pattern = "\|{5,}"
strNewText = re.Replace(strText, "")

Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(strSource, ForWriting, True)
file.WriteLine strNewText
file.Close
```

NB. Consider using `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your script; it will save you from misspelled and confused variables.